# Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

creating an application in react-native running into this problem. basically I should create a page that prints the data of the user currently logged in to the database (firebase). I managed to create a sort of leaderboard that prints all users with data, on another page, but I can not figure out where I was wrong. can someone help me?

https://snack.expo.io/@khal_d/proj-p-3

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Button, Text, ScrollView, ListItem } from 'react-native';
import { Input, Card} from 'react-native-elements';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';


export default class User extends Component {
   static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'UserInfo',
  };

  state = {
    data: [],
  };

  // Controllare qui
  componentDidMount(){
    //leggere array dal db
    const currentUID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const path ="/users/" + currentUID;
    const users = firebase.database().ref(path);
    users.on("value", snap => {
      console.log("log di snap" + snap);
      //ciclo
      var elenco = [];
      snap.forEach(child => {
        elenco.push({
          name: child.val().name,
          surname: child.val().surname,
          email: child.val().email,
          image: child.val().image,
        })
      });

      console.log("altro log finale" + elenco);
      this.setState({data:elenco})
    });

  }

// controllare fino a qua

  render() {

    return (
      <ScrollView>
      <View>
        <Card> //fix evertything all'interno di card
          {
    this.state.data.map((l, i) => (
      <ListItem
        key={i}
        leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: l.image } }}
        title={l.name}
        subtitle={l.surname}

      />
    ))
  }
        </Card>
      </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the comments and extra `{` `}`from your code in render() or use them as below. In JSX you cannot have `//` in render():

```
 render() {

    return (
      <ScrollView>
      <View>
        <Card> 

    { this.state.data && 
    this.state.data.map((l, i) => (
      <ListItem
        key={i}
        leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: l.image } }}
        title={l.name}
        subtitle={l.surname}

      />
    ))
    }

      </Card>
      </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

iOS has no problem with extra syntaxes in `render()`, but in android it will show that error.

Also because of asynchronous problem of `setState`, you will have and error of `undefined is not an object`. So it is better to have  `{this.state.data &&`  condition on your ListItem.  I hope I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is because of the comment. In JSX, comment with  // doesn't work. It will be treated as a text.

You have to change your comments like below which will fix your issue

```
    {/* fix evertything all'interno di card */}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListItem` should be imported from `react-native-elements` and not from `react-native`.